# openssl commands on JS front end

Tags: javascript, encryption, openssl

Hello i have tried to replicate these commands on JS using crypto js with no success

```
openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in #{file.key} -passin pass:#{password} -out myPrivate.key
```

with this i obtain an rsa encoded private key i can work with, to calculate it's modulus and compare it with another file

```
openssl rsa -in myPrivate.key -noout -modulus
openssl x509 -inform DER -in certificate.cer -noout -modulus
```

if the output of these 2 it's equal, the user is authorized, however i have tried to replicate this on JS with [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) with no success, it keeps throwing errors when i have the files read on strings and trying to pass them to it.

Could someone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I question simply checking to see if the modulus of the private key and that of the public key are the same in order to determine if a user is authorized or not. That being said, using forge, I believe this should do what you're asking:

```
function isAuthorized(privateKeyPem, password, certificatePem) {
  var privateKey = forge.pki.decryptRsaPrivateKey(
    privateKeyPem, password);

  var certificate = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(certificatePem);
  var publicKey = certificate.publicKey;

  // returns true when modulus is the same
  return privateKey.n.compareTo(publicKey.n) === 0;
}
```

If you are using a private key that isn't encrypted then use this instead (to convert from PEM format):

```
var privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(privateKeyPem);
```